# page.waitForFunction not working as expected Playwright.js

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm trying to debug my logic inside of [page.waitForFunction](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-arg-options) but nothing I log out gets printed. If I try to use the VScode debugger it ignores any breakpoints inside the callback function. If I place a break point before the `await page.waitForFunction()` call and then try to step through it I just end up in `/internal/async_hooks` and then get stuck through a bunch of node internals. Again if I try to place a breakpoint inside the callback and jump to that, it doesn't stop.

I have no idea what's going on. Am I using it wrong or something? Or completely misunderstanding how it works?

Here's a simple example.

```js
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const i = 0;
  await page
    .waitForFunction(
      (i) => {
        i++;
        console.log(`---> evaluating # ${i}`);
        if (i < 3) return false;
        return true;
      },
      i,
      { timeout: 3000 }
    )
    .catch(console.error);
  console.log("done");
  await browser.close();
})();
```

For this code I expect it to log out

```js
// ---> evaluating #1
// ---> evaluating #2
// done
```

Instead, nothing from within the callback is logged out and it just logs out

```js
// done
```

If I always return `false` in the callback, then it errors with `Timeout 3000ms exceeded.Error` as expected, so it's like it's working, but I have no way to debug what's going on inside the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things there:

First, the function you pass to `waitForFunction` is being executed inside the browser. So you won't see that log in your app, unless you get the log using the `console` event.

Second, and related to the previous point. That function will always get `0` in the `i` argument because `i` is incremented inside the browser. Which doesn't affect the variable that will be passed over and over.

Comment: Aaah, okay thanks. So I guess I'm using the wrong tool for what I'm trying achieve. I didn't realise that it's executed in the browser, I thought it's the same as Selenium's wait method that just re-evaluates it's callback until it returns true.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I basically just wanted a helper method to wait until a certain condition is true. In this specific case, a venue name is appended to the text of `<h2>Seat reviews for </h2>`, slightly after the page is loaded but the timing is flakey. So I basically want to just say wait until the h2's text is no longer "Seat reviews for" before doing an assertion with jest.

I wrote my own helper that basically just evaluates a callback, if it returns false then calls `await page.waitForTimeout(500)` and retries it again. And then just fails after 10 retries.